# Match for script tag and remove it using prototype

Tags: javascript, tags, prototypejs, pattern-matching

I have a bunch of script tags on my page, and I want to remove any script tag that includes the the words: 'js/calendar_SHA1_'.

I am using the protype javascript library. Is there a really efficient way to match for the aforementioned string and remove it from the page?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The code is below:

```
var scripts = $$('script[src]');
```

var patt = /calendar_SHA1_/gi;

for(var i=0;i < scripts.length;i++){

`if(scripts[i].src.match(patt)){
scripts[i].remove();
 }`

}